# Recursive function with only one parent and one request

Tags: php, recursion

I want to display a tree of folders. My folders have security access. I define the security only for the first folder, after each subfolder herit.

I want to build a recursive function to display all folders available.

Here is my data :

```
Folder 1 : {parent, id, label, security_access}
    - Folder 2 :  {parent, id, label}
    - Folder 3 :  {parent, id, label}
         - Folder 4 :  {parent, id, label}
Folder 5 : {parent, id, label, security_access}
    - Folder 6 :  {parent, id, label}
...
```

So I get first level folders with security_access (considering $free_folders variable), but how to loop through subfolders ? With only 1 database request, I have a lot of folders and I can't have 200 requests. 
Here is my code and I can't find when to use recursion :

```
$folders = $this->db->get_where('file', array('mime' => 'directory'))->result();
$folders_output = array();

foreach($folders as $folder)
{
    $folders_all[$folder->parent_id][] = array(
        'label' => $folder->name,
        'parent' => $folder->parent_id,
        'id' => $folder->id,
    );
}   

foreach ($folders as $folder)
{
    // Get first level folders (parent_id = 1)
    // $folder_free contains files accessible to users
    if ($folder->parent_id == 1 && in_array($folder->id, $folders_free))
    {
        $folders_output[$folder->id]->parent = $folder->parent_id;     
        $folders_output[$folder->id]->label = $folder->name;     
        $folders_output[$folder->id]->id = $folder->id;       
    }
}

// Loop each first level folder
$_parent = 0;

foreach($folders_output as $id => $folder)
{
    do 
    {
        // ... 14th infinite loop
                    // How can I push each subfolders of my first level folder ? 
        $parent = $folders_all[$id][0]['parent'];
    }
    while ($_parent != 1);
}

// Show unordored list with folders - works !
$treeview = $this->treeview(1, 0, $folders_output);
```

I really can't find the easiest solution.. Thanks !

Ok I think it's ok .. I used recursive function, not really a smart way I think when I see my results... :

```
foreach($folders_free as $folder)
{
    $_results[] = $this->_dossiers($folders_all, $folder);
}

------------------------------------------------

private function _dossiers($array, $parent)
{
    $results = array();

    foreach ($array AS $entry) 
    {
        if ($entry->parent == $parent) 
        {
            $object = new stdClass();                            
            $object->parent = $entry->parent;                    
            $object->id = $entry->id;                    
            $object->label = $entry->label;
            $results[] = $object;

            // Recursive call
            $results[] = $this->_dossiers($array, $entry->id);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? SO is not a place where someone will write the code for you but we're happy to help when you have a specific problem.

Comment: You are totally right ! I am sorry, I posted my code. But I wrote a lot for no result ..

Comment: The code is damn hard to understand. What do you want to accomplish with that, for example, `$folders_output[$folder->id]->parent = $folder->parent_id;`?. $folders_output should be empty at this point.

Comment: And what is that your folder structure?. is that a nested array?

Comment: Also, how do you know if a folder has a subfolder?

Comment: Cause : $folder->parent_id = $parent->id. I want to push in $folders_ouput all subfolders of each accessible folder, using only one request. But I can't find how to loop efficiently.